# Which semimartingale representation does the process $U_t = 2 + t^2 + \sin(B_t)\;, t \in [0, \infty)$ satisfy?

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B)_{t≥0}$ be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}$ and let the process $(U)_{t≥0}$
defined by $$U_t = 2 + t^2 + \sin(B_t)\;, t \in  [0, \infty).$$
Which semimartingale representation does the process $U$ satisfy?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: As usual: Apply Itô's formula. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @saz The problem is that I'm new in this field, that's why I don't know how to solve this kind of exercises.

Comment: Step 1: Apply Itô's formula to get a semimartingale representation for $\sin(B_t)$.